# Bash - split text and number/numbers from one var

Tags: bash, variables, text, split

I have one problem.
I have VAR - for example:

> $VAR="test12"

And I want to split it to 2 parts.
But I don't know how to do this.
I tried that:

> SECOND_PART="${VAR: -1}"
>
> FIRST_PART="${VAR%?}"

but this method does not include multi-digit numbers (range: 1 to 99).
Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo  ${VAR//[^0-9]/}  ${VAR//[0-9]/}
```

This uses pattern substitution. It also assumes the form of the input is reliable (e.g. not `"this12andthat98"`)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

```
echo  ${VAR%%[0-9]*}  ${VAR##*[!0-9]}
test 12
```

- `${VAR%%[0-9]*}` 
   Removes the longest number match from behind. So
  `test12` will become `test`.
- `${VAR##*[!0-9]}`
   Removes the longest match from front. So `test12`
  will become `12`. The match states to match anything except a number.